How to know the formula of function in mathematica?
When I review BiorthogonalSplineWavelet in official website.
I could not find any formula of how to calculate  as below:

How to know the formula or equation of one function in Mathematica？

Related: FunctionExpand

Do you mean $\ast$ as the convolution?
